# Is there any option for excluding the errored out record and continue writing in SQL SERVER using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I have tried below solution, But it will not load any data if there is any bad row.

```
val test = df.write.mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", sqlurl).option("dbtable", "SQLTABLE").    option("driver",driver_new).option("principal", principal).option("keytab", keytab).save()
```

Comment: can you explain bad rows? what kind of bad rows causing issues in writing?

Comment: Example: If the length of the inserting column is more than actual column size, In this case Can I exclude that row and continue loading?